# QMessageBox crash when using QStyle::drawControl in a QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: qt, crash, qmessagebox

I have an odd problem.

I am using `QStyle`'s `drawControl()` to draw a progress bar in a custom `QStyledItemDelegate`'s paint().

Now the application crashes, when I try to open a `QMessageBox` with either `show()` or `exec()` or whatever.

I am quite sure, that this is not my fault and that it is exactly this combination.

I wrote a quite minimal example project, that shows the problem.

This is the delegate's `paint()`:

```
void ItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
QStyleOptionProgressBar progressBarOption;
progressBarOption.rect = option.rect;
progressBarOption.minimum = 0;
progressBarOption.maximum = 100;
progressBarOption.progress = index.data().toInt();

// This line crashes a QMessageBox. CE_ProgressBarContents and CE_ProgressBar lead to a crash. 
// All other values of QStyle::CE_*** work fine.
// drawComplexControl has no problem either.
QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ProgressBarContents, &progressBarOption, painter);
}
```

If I set this delegate on a QTreeView (which of course has items) and open a QMessageBox, the application crashes.

The example project can be found [on my GitHub](https://github.com/Kampfgnom/QMessageBoxCrash).

I also opened a [discussion on qtcentre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53346-QMessageBox-crash-when-using-QStyle-drawControl-somewhere-else?p=238976#post238976) with additional information.

I am using Qt 5.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.2. Is this a Qt bug? How would you work around it?

Comment: Since I didn't get any reply on here or on qtcentre, I filed a bug report: [QTBUG-29748](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29748)

Comment: It was in fact a bug in Qt and it will be fixed in 5.0.2.